# how to pass values from a one2many field to another field in different model of same form? form view image given below (ial)

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-8

[ial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MOPY.png)

```
one2many field name: survey_request_ids
model of one2many field : hr_evaluation.evaluation
Field name of 'Interviewer' inside one2many : user_id
model of 'Interviewer' inside one2many : hr.evaluation.interview
```

I want to create a new field 'Interviewer' below 'Appraisal Deadline'
which will have values from the below field 'Interviewer' which is in a one2many.

I tried like these,

```
from openerp import models,fields,api

class hr_evaluation_interview(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.evaluation.interview'

    @api.onchange('user_id')
    def _onchange_user_id(self):
        rec = self.env['hr_evaluation.evaluation'].search([('id','=', 
self.evaluation_id.id)])
        rec.update({
            'interviewer_ids': [(4,self.user_id.id)]
        })


class hr_evaluation_inherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr_evaluation.evaluation'

    _columns = {
        'interviewer_ids': fields.many2many('res.users', 
string='Interviewer',readonly=True)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed many2many field. The compute method will loop through all the appraisal forms and create a recordset containing all the interviewers that appear in all the forms. Then populate the many2many field with that recordset.

It would look something like this:

```
def _compute_interviewer_ids(self):
    for record in self:
        interviewer_ids = []
        for appraisal_form in record.survey_request_ids:
            interviewer_ids.append(appraisal_form.interviewer_id.id)
        record.interviewer_ids = self.env['interviewer.model'].browse(interviewer_ids)


interviewer_ids = fields.Many2many('interviewer.model', compute='_compute_interviewer_ids', string='Interviewers')
```

Edit: here is an entire model and its submodel so you can see it in context. Tested in v12.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'example_module.example_model'
    _description = 'Example Model'

    def _compute_interviewer_ids(self):
        for record in self:
            interviewer_ids = []
            for appraisal_form in record.submodel_ids:
                interviewer_ids.append(appraisal_form.partner_id.id)
            record.interviewer_ids = self.env['res.partner'].browse(interviewer_ids)

    name = fields.Char()
    description = fields.Text()
    submodel_ids = fields.One2many('example_module.example_sub_model', 'examplemodel_id', 'SubModel Records')
    interviewer_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', compute='_compute_interviewer_ids', string='Interviewers')

class ExampleSubModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'example_module.example_sub_model'
    _description = 'Example Sub-model'

    name = fields.Char()
    examplemodel_id = fields.Many2one('example_module.example_model', 'Parent Record')
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Partner')
```

Comment: This is not an onchange method, it's a compute method. I tested the code and it's working fine on my end. I will edit my post with the whole model and submodel for your reference